# getName() call on SimpleXMLElement returns fatal error "call to member function on a non-object"

Tags: php, simplexml

I am experiencing a very odd error. I am writing a function to validate XML based on element names, in this case passed in as an array. First, I normalize the input to a `SimpleXMLElement` object; in this case I am passing in a DOMDocument, and I tested it, it is converting correctly to `SimpleXMLElement`.

What confuses me is that calling `getName()` will throw the following:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getName() on a non-object
```

But using `exit($xml->getName())` (or `echo`) will return the correct result - the root element name!

Relevant code:

```
function validateXML($xml, $format='') {
(get_class($xml) !== 'SimpleXMLElement') ?
    ((get_class($xml) === 'DOMDocument') ?
        $xml = simplexml_import_dom($xml)
        : $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml))
    : $xml = $xml;
$rootName = ($xml->getName());
if ($rootName != $format[0]) {
    exit($xml->getName())));
}
```

Also, in case it matters, the server is running PHP 5.3

I am very new to PHP so help is extremely appreciated!

P.S. To be clear about what exactly is going on, the following code:

```
function validateXML($xml, $format='') {
    echo(get_class($xml);
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($xml);
    echo(get_class($xml);
    echo($xml->getName());
}
```

outputs to the server

```
DOMDocument
SimpleXMLElement
'ElementName' (the correct root name of my XML document)
```

... so it appears to be working, except that the fatal error still gets thrown.

Comment: Re: "_so it appears to be working, except that the fatal error still gets thrown._": Show us the code that throws the exception. The function you have given obviously does _not_ throw the exception you mentioned, so there is something more, or the error is thrown some other time. This error to occur needs `$xml` to be something else than what you have said - is not `SimpleXMLElement` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (assuming it is close enough to what you have written in the question) will fail when `$xml` is invalid XML, because [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php):

> **Returns** an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the xml document, or **FALSE on failure**.

If you still do not see this, I suggest rewriting your code using `if` statements instead of tertiary statements. Your function, when `$xml` is not `SimpleXMLElement` instance, nor `DOMDocument` instance, will be effectively coming down to the following function:

```
function validateXML($xml, $format='') {
    simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $rootName = ($xml->getName());
    if ($rootName != $format[0]) {
        exit($xml->getName());
    };
}
```

Comment: I definitely appreciate the feedback, but again, the first part of my function is performing as expected. Firstly, after passing in a DOMDocument, and calling `get_class()` on the result, it returns to me `SimpleXMLElement`, which tells me that the problem is more elusive. Perhaps I didn't state this clear enough - I used the `exit` and `echo` commands on the input, and they did return the correct result of calling `getName()`, but it still throws the fatal error as well.

Comment: @user1575456: I was not talking about that case, I was talking about the case when you receive something _different_. I believe the best here would be the exact code and input value (both narrowed to smallest code reproducing the issue) you use. Then it should be clear what is the issue, and I think this will show you the real nature of the problem. So, again: please give us the piece of code that after running produces what you have described (namely: throws an exception).